# Xcode 6.1 if/else/for/switch statements not autocompleting (Swift only)

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, swift, autocomplete

I am not experiencing the autocomplete problem described in every other post. Normal function autocomplete works just fine. My issue is the version of Xcode I am running (6.1, Swift) will not autocomplete / auto-suggest any basic program statement (if, for, switch, do, etc.). If I type "if" for example, after a few seconds the suggestion menu pops up; however, there is no documentation in the window which would normally describe a statement's function (while at the same time presenting an auto laid-out example to fill in).

If I try a project in the same version of Xcode in Objective-C, these basic program statements complete just fine.

I have already:

1) Make sure my Settings are set to auto-suggest completions
2) Make sure I have cleared DerivedData and everything else suggested in previous posts
3) Reinstalled Xcode & restarted Mac countless times
4) Downloaded all latest "iOS 8.1, Xcode 6.1" documentation from "Xcode -> Preferences -> Documentation"

This used to work!! Arrgh. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: XCode + Swift is unstable (not officially) at the moment. Upgrading to the XCode 6.2 beta fixed this for me. Though, I still get the annoying crash every now and again.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Xcode 6.2 and clear your derived data. It should fix the problem.

Comment: I just upgraded and cleared derived data. Still no luck. All "if/else/for/switch/do" statements have no autocomplete/autofill, and no code snippets of description in the pop-up menu.

Comment: What I've tested is I can drag the appropriate code-snippet from the snippet library in the Utilities panel into the code view. I just can't start typing the snippet and select from the autocomplete view.